# In circuitikz multiwire: How to so specify label placement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels, circuitikz

Circuitikz has the nice

`\draw (a) to[multiwire=n] (b);`

option, drawing a slash across a wire to indicate bus width. It places the slash and the label n in the middle. Is there any convenient way to place it elsewhere? Usual tikz options like "near end" have no effect. No other multiwire-related questions here are not pertinent.

Comment: Position of bipoles are hardwired to the middle of line. As possible workaround can be split line to two parts:  `\draw (a) to[multiwire=n] (b) -- (c);

Comment: Best is to use: `\draw (0,0) to[multiwire=n] ++(1,0) to[short] ++(2,0);`

Comment: Thanks. I was playing around with splitting line, but it is a bit cumbersome. But good to know I am not overlooking anything.

Comment: Most (if not all) bipoles can also be accessed as nodes: `\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) node[multiwireshape, pos=0.1, label=n, sloped]{};`

Comment: Both comments from @Zarko and... (next comment)

Comment: ...and from @JohnKormylo are correct --- you can always devise a macro, but basically those are the two options. Changing the positioning of the element in `circuitikz` to respect `pos` would be a, well, major change.

Comment: @Rmano thanks, I think I prefer the simple multiwireshape approach. Probably cleanest. If you turn it into an answer, I'd love to accept it.

Comment: It should be transformed into an answer by @JohnKormylo... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As both [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611251/in-circuitikz-multiwire-how-to-so-specify-label-placement#comment1528818_611251) and [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611251/in-circuitikz-multiwire-how-to-so-specify-label-placement#comment1529010_611251) commented, `circuitikz` position the components mid-way the coordinates of the `to` path. Changing it isn't simple, because you should consider the component size and the scaling of the current path...

As a workaround, if you need to position many of them, you can use a macro (ah, the power of TeX); the following one is a dirty hack that works for positions between 0.1 and 0.9:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\mwire}[3]{% args: position (0.1-0.9), label, final coordinate
    % remove `node{x}` which is here just for debug
    coordinate(tmp1) #3 node{x} coordinate(tmp2)
    (tmp1) -- ($(tmp1)!{#1-0.1}!(tmp2)$) to[multiwire=#2] ($(tmp1)!{#1+0.1}!(tmp2)$) -- (tmp2)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,2) \mwire{0.7}{2}{++(3,0)};
    \draw (0,1) \mwire{0.2}{2}{++(3,0)};
    \draw (0,0) \mwire{0.7}{4}{++(3,0)} to[R] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]